# Dark Toolbar with Light App Theme

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I know this question has been asked before, and it worked for me before but after updating to App Compat revision 23, the Toolbar is now having a black text color (I want it white) and I didn't change a thing.

Toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="@attr/spinner_style">@style/spinner_style</item>
</style>
```

Setting toolbar to activity:

```
 Toolbar Toolbar = (Toolbar) AppCompatActivity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(Toolbar);
 ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)activity).getSupportActionBar();
 actionBar.setTitle(title);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

to

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

Comment: Ok thanks man it worked! but can you explain why i had to change that. knowing that it used to work in AppCompat revision 22

Comment: @rashad.z it was an internal change. You were right using `local:theme` before, but now (from the v23 release I think) the support classes read from the `android:theme` attribute so if you use the local namespace it will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The new support libraries (AppCompat) that Android Studio brings in default project templates do not insert an important attribute to style Toolbars in older Android versions.

This is what worked for me (I'm using an AppBarLayout with Toolbar and TabLayout, as shown):

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" <!-- Needed attribute -->
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" <!-- Needed attribute -->
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

I didn't research to know exactly what happened here, but older Android versions really need the theme in every element to be styled.

Hope it helps someone who is trying to find a solution to the black text in the light toolbar theme!