# menu 3 dots and App name are not visiible due to white toolbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-toolbar

I want to use the white toolbar in my app. But when I change the color then the three dots of the menu is not visible as its color is also white. Also, the name of the app in the toolbar is also not visible. How to change the color of these two(app name and menu dots). My xml code -

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/home_toolbar_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_tab_lyt_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        style="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:tabTextColor="#000">

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

Comment: What theme you are using ?

Comment: In case if you are using AppCompat the best way is to modify textColorSecondary in your theme for changing the icon color as well

Answer (score 0):

Hear is method that can you change both toolbar text and menu color programatically

```
public static void setOverflowColor(final Toolbar toolbar, final int color) {
Drawable drawable = toolbar.getOverflowIcon();
if(drawable != null) {
    drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable.mutate(), color);
    toolbar.setOverflowIcon(drawable);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(color)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the toolbar theme to light.
This [Dark Toolbar with Light App Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101818/dark-toolbar-with-light-app-theme) can help you to find a solution for your probelm.